# PyMC: Switch stochastic variable observed flag

Tags: pymc

On my test set, the observed variables are not the same for each data point. A given variable can be observed on a data point, and not on the next one. Thus I would like to change the observed flag of those variables without reconstructing the full PyMC model. I read that it wasn't possible (and couldn't manage to do it).  Is there any way to do it?

I thus decided to rebuild a PyMC model for each of my test set data point. I instantiate a new PyMC model at each iteration of a for loop.

The problem is that it seems that the memory used by each PyMC model is not deleted. The fact is that my network is huge (1000 binomial/sigmoid nodes) and densely connected. The model takes about 200MB (just the model, without the traces). I am wondering if maybe the python garbage collector wasn't able to delete it because of the numerous circular references between the PyMC nodes of my network.

What do you think? Do you see a proper way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are rebuilding the PyMC model for each data point, then presumably you are not using the built-in samplers (e.g. MCMC).  In that case, you can use the `set_value()` method of the nodes you need to set at each iteration and then call `model.draw_from_prior()` to get draw a random value for the other nodes.

In other words, instead of using `observed=True`, you can create your nodes with `observed=False` and then manually fix the value with `set_value()`.